# Jena Fuseki GeoSPARQL: cannot delete data

Tags: python, sparql, jena, fuseki, geosparql

Trying to delete data from a Jena Fuseki server running the GeoSPARQL extension.

The queries don't seem to be effective.

The output from the server when trying either `DELETE` or `DELETE DATA` is:

```
23:29:06 WARN  Fuseki     :: [2] Parse error: Encountered " "delete" "DELETE "" at line 15, column 1.
23:29:52 WARN  Fuseki     :: [4] Parse error: Encountered " <DELETE_DATA> "DELETE DATA "" at line 15, column 1.
```

Command to run the server, from scratch without an empty index and tdb file:

```sh
java -jar jena-fuseki-geosparql-4.2.0.jar  \
  -rf file.n3 \
  --index_expiry 50000000000000,500000000000,500000000000 -p 3034 \
  -t ./geosparql-tdb2 \
  -t2 --update \
  --spatial_index ./geosparql-tdb2/spatial.index
```

(`prefix spa: <http://jena.apache.org/spatial#>`)

The delete query is thus:

```
DELETE DATA { ?feature a sosa:featureOfInterest . }
WHERE {
  ?feature a sosa:featureOfInterest ;
  spa:withinBox(54.3 -116.5 34.2 -93.9) .
}
```

Which corresponds to a select query which is working as expected (i.e. is correctly selecting the rows which should be deleted):

```
select * WHERE {
  ?feature spa:withinBox(54.3 -116.5 34.2 -93.9) .
}
```

Any ideas?

**Edit:**
The delete query which was causing the parse error was incorrect. This new delete query doesn't cause an error. However, this still doesn't delete the data.

```
DELETE {
  ?g a geo:Geometry .
}
WHERE {
  ?g a geo:Geometry .
  ?g spa:withinBox(54.3 -116.5 34.2 -93.9) .
}
```

Also, the query URL is `/ds/query` and the delete URL is `/ds/update`.

Finally, the request is being performed in python as follows:

```py
def run_sparql(s, qtype='query'):
  url = 'http://localhost:3034/ds/' + qtype
  payload = s
  headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/sparql-query'}
  res = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

The response code for the `delete` query is `415` while for the select it is `200`.

**Edit #2:**
Changing the content type from `application/sparql-query` to `application/sparql-update` results in a status code of `400` and still does not delete the data as expected.

To be clear:

```py
s = '''
prefix geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#> 
prefix spa: <http://jena.apache.org/spatial#>
DELETE {
  ?g a geo:Geometry .
}
WHERE {
  ?g a geo:Geometry .
  ?g spa:withinBox(54.3 -116.5 34.2 -93.9) .
}
'''

url = 'http://localhost:3034/ds/update'
payload = s
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/sparql-update'}
res = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers)
```

Even this is not working:

```
prefix geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#> 
DELETE {?g a geo:Geometry}
```

Comment: are you using the correct URL for the update requests? It should be `.../ds/update` and not `.../ds/query`

Comment: by the way, `DELETE DATA` has no `WHERE` part  - either `DELETE DATA {}` or `DELETE {} WHERE {}` but not mixed

Comment: @UninformedUser Thanks for both tips. Using `/ds/query` to query and `/ds/update` in attempting to delete. `DELETE DATA {}` and `DELETE {} WHERE {}` both are causing "Parse error" to appear in the Fuseki server output.

Comment: @UninformedUser Upon further inspection it looks like "Parse error" is occurring only when using either `DELETE DATA` with `WHERE` or `DELETE` alone.

Comment: sure, both are wrong. `DELETE {} WHERE {}` is the correct one. Does it work now or not? I'm a bit confused by your edit. Also, now that you show your Python code, for update requests the content type is also different, it should be `application/sparql-update`, see: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-protocol/#update-operation

Comment: @UninformedUser I happened to try `application/sparql-update` out of intuition but it returned `400`. Then I was trying to find documentation on the content type but couldn't, so thanks for sharing a link!